# Get the category from custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, categories

I used this code to post articles on the front end:

```
//the array of args to be inserted with `wp_insert_post()`:
$new_post = array(
    'post_title'    => $title,
    'post_content'  => $content,
    'tags_input'    => $tags,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_category' => array('0',$_POST['cat']),         
    'post_type'     => $post_type 
);
```

It worked when I was using the post type `article` but I have created a custom post type and then, can't get the category any more...

What do I have to change with `array('0',$_POST['cat'])` to get the category from my custom post type?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is building the write screen for you to post on the frontend may be including the Categories on the screen, and adding them to `$_POST`, but your CPTs still must be registered to use them. I assume the `Articles` CPT had this, and you may have missed that step in creating yours.

### Check you have registered categories for your CPT

1) be sure your CPT has `'taxonomies' => array( 'category' )` in the `$args` array.

Side note: to add the wordpress category taxonomy after a post_type has been registered, you can also use [`register_taxonomy_for_object_type( $taxonomy, $object_type );`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type) where `$taxonomy` is `'category'` and `$object_type` is `'your_post_type'`

### Quick check of $_POST['cat']

2) if all good with the above, be sure the `'$new_post'` array is receiving the correct input. If you may have more than one category, be sure `$_POST['cat']` is giving you an array, if not create the array outside of the `$new_post` declaration and pass it in.

```
    if (is_array($_POST['cat']) {
        $category_array = $_POST['cat'];
    }
   else { //for some reason we have a string
       $category_array[] = $_POST['cat'];
    }

   $new_post = array(
    'post_title'    => $title,
    'post_content'  => $content,
    'tags_input'    => $tags,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_category' => $category_array,         
    'post_type'     => $post_type 
);
```

### Custom Taxonomy Scenario for Clarification

(*since this would have to be added to whatever is generating the post creation screen, I doubt this is the issue, but I'll add this in for information*)

If your category is a [taxonomy you registered](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) (i.e. Genre for a Books CPT), `$new_post` will need `tax_input` [as described in `wp_insert_post` parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/#parameters), as an array just like above with category.

Assuming your `$_POST` has a field for `'my_taxonomy'`, that is an array of selected `my_taxonomy` options from the write screen, i.e.:

```
 $_POST['my_taxonomy'] = array(
                           'my_taxonomy' => $entered_value[0],
                           'my_taxonomy' => $entered_value[1]
                         )
```

`$new_post` would look something like this:

```
   $new_post = array(
    'post_title'    => $title,
    'post_content'  => $content,
    'tags_input'    => $tags,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_tax'      => $_POST['my_taxonomy'],         
    'post_type'     => $post_type 
);
```

### previous answer regarding post_type

Your custom post type would be getting declared in the post_type line.
`'post_type' => $post_type );`
You need to edit the value of the variable `$post_type` so it is `name_of_your_post_type`

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering quickly ! the var $post_type is already loaded with the name of my custom post type name....

Comment: ah, ok. You need the **Category** of your **CPT**... I may have read too hastily. The category in question is the default wordpress category taxonomy, yes? Or have you made a new taxonomy for your new CPT? If the latter, you need to pass a different value and I'll update the answer.

Comment: I've updated this for what I'm guessing may be the cause, and then added some other things to look at it not.